# Updating Mule mmc 3.5.2 agent?

Tags: mule, agent

I am updating Mule ESB, MMC to 3.5.2 from 3.3.2

I could access Server, flow information of apps deployed in mule esb except Agent App using MMC Rest API http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/REST+API+Reference (e.g. /mmc/api/servers and /mmc/api/servers/local$70951c37-4d9a-4eb8-96f6-b358433a85a6/flows).

In this API I could access all the apps deployed in mule ESB except MMC Agent App.What configuration I need to deploy mmc agent as mule app. I have downloaded mule esb enterprise version in which mule mmc and Agent comes. so its not license issue.

What are detailed steps to migrate to Mule ESB, MMC 3.5.2?

PFA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MMC 3.5.x agent is not a Mule application anymore, it's bundled with Mule ESB EE, so you won't find it when listing applications.

Comment: Thank you Ale for a quick response.I could see my server/application are in running state. I could get the flow of my applications. But strangely I am getting below exception in my mule_ee.log.          Pinging the JVM took 7 seconds to respond.
Pinging the JVM took 3 seconds to respond.
ERROR 2014-11-17 23:12:21,071 [qtp667713355-133] com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter: null
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914)
com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter.doFilter(ConsoleClientCertFilter.java:138)

Comment: I have no idea, try submitting a ticket to support@mulesoft.com